# Android Studio illegal state exception: cannot find method (view) for android:onClick

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using radio buttons to switch the colors in a project. When the user clicks one of the radio buttons, I want the associated theme to be saved to SharedPreferences. The necessary themes are set up, but upon clicking a radio button, this error is thrown:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onThemeRadio(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.RadioButton with id 'theme2'
```

The relevant XML and Java blocks are shown below.
Java:

```
    public void onThemeRadio(View view){
    SharedPreferences themeStorage = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor themeStorageEditor = themeStorage.edit();
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton)view).isChecked();
    int themeId = themeStorage.getInt("themeId",1);
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.theme1:
            if (checked)
                themeId = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.theme2:
            if (checked)
                themeId = 2;
            break;
        case R.id.theme3:
            if (checked)
                themeId = 3;
            break;
    }
    themeStorageEditor.putInt("themeId",themeId);
    themeStorageEditor.apply();
}
```

XML:

```
            <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/themeRadio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/theme1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/theme1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onThemeRadio"
            android:text="Default Theme" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/theme2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onThemeRadio"
            android:text="Alternate Theme" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/theme3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onThemeRadio"
            android:text="Combined Theme" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

I've read a few similar issues, but none of the fixes worked or applied.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The relevant Java code you included, the onThemeRadio() method exists as a member of the Activity class that has the XML you included as its content view?

Comment: @GregMoens It is. Settings.java includes the the line: setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings); in its onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell based on the limited code you provided. But based on the error message, it would seem that you do not have the onThemeRadio(View) method in the right place. It needs to be a method on the Activity class that uses that XML layout. Use Android Studio to help figure it out. For example, does Android Studio highlight onThemeRadio(View) as an unused method? Or does the onclick attribute in XML get flagged that the method is missing or has the wrong signature? These are signs that the method is in the wrong place. You can also use the light bulb that pops up next to a highlighted onclick attribute to automatically create the method in the right place.